# Inserting a fixed date within a condition in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I want to create a condition that, if it exists, its execution date will be preserved

For example, if the number 10 appears in a cell today, I want the today's date (17/5/17) to be stored in the cell next to it, and tomorrow the **today's** date (17/5/17) will appear in the cell.

So I tried to use functions like TODAY or DATE, but if i use them - then tomorrow the date in the cell will change to tomorrow's date.

How can I keep the first date of the condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not with formulas. A formula using Today() will always recalculate to deliver today's date. That's the purpose of the Today() function.

For a static time stamp, you will need to engage VBA to capture today's date and write it as a hard coded (or **constant**) value, so that it will **not** be updated when the sheet is recalculated.

You may want to research topics like "Excel date stamp" or "Excel time stamp" for VBA code examples that use that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You still use the function TODAY... but you will need to write a Workbook_Open subroutine (which will automatically run once every time the workbook is open) to change the formula to actual date value...

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off the automatic update in the calculation options of formula so that it only updates when you press F9. But this means that if the value of your reference cell changes then today's date will not be modified, even if you want it to.